# Reduce "boldness" of text-converted shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, shapes, path

As a newbie to Illustrator, I'm struggling to find a way to reduce the "boldness" of the shape converted from text (see image). Is there a way to reduce the line thickness of this shape?

[image]

Comment: Offset? Nudge? Drag? Though why one just wouldnt redraw that particular shape is beyond me.

Comment: The method could be applicable to any text-converted shape, the square bracket is used just as an example.

Comment: there is no one generic method. I general you have to redraw the shapes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the text has been converted to paths, it might be possible to use an Offset Path effect, although it might not work so well on all glyphs of a font.

Open up the appearance panel, hit the *fx button > Path > Offset path*, and choose a small negative value. If you go too far, it won't look good.

An example

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's also the quicker way where you just apply a white stroke and play with the thickness of that stroke, but this doesn't really affect the shape, it just adds a white overlay all over the edges.